# Is the formula $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det (A) }\text{Adj}(A)$ really true for 2 x 2 matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, determinant, inverse

Given a 2 x 2 matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$, we have the [inverse formula](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-inverse.html) $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a \end{bmatrix}$.

But isn't $\text{Adj}(A)$ equal to $\begin{bmatrix} d & -c \\ -b & a \end{bmatrix}$? So don't we have $\frac{1}{\det (A)}\text{Adj}(A)=\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix} d & -c \\ -b & a \end{bmatrix} \ne \begin{bmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: $\operatorname{Adj}(A)$ is the transpose of what you wrote.

Comment: Huh?  No, that's not the adjugate. The cited formula for the inverse is correct.

Comment: Thanks @anomaly, that explains it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is true for all square invertible matrices. For adjoint A you have to take transpose of 'cofactor matrix of A'. You have not taken transpose.